# programmatically pass cell value to title in GT tab_header

Tags: r, gt

I would like to use the value in a specific column as the title for my gt table.
All rows in the title column have the same character value.
How do I reference a column in tab_header

I want to do this because I am making many tables from a large dataframe, each of which will have a different title

Here is example data

```
d <- data.frame(
          organism=c("Grasshopper", "Bumblebee", "MycoTB"), 
          protein=c("Jumpylegs", "venom-1", "rpoB"), 
          accession=c("Gr1,Gr2,Gr3", "Bbv4,Bbv5,Bbv6", "Mtb1,Mtb2,Mtb3,Mtb4,Mtb5"), 
          title = c("mytitle", "mytitle", "mytitle")
)
```

Here is my code

```
d %>%
          gt() %>%
          tab_header(
                    title = # here I want to get the text from the title column, somthing like .$title[1]
                
          )
```

Comment: Maybe `title = unique(d$title)`?

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for the solve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = .$`_data`$title[1]
  )
```

When you convert your data to a `gt` object, you can access the data elements in the list using `_data`.

This gives us:

[image]